# How to make graduated symbology icons visible in the exported map images of MapServer of ArcGis?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, symbology

We created a new mxd file. We created a new layer using "Make a Feature Layer" command. Then we selected the new layer and got into the Symbology properties. There we created Quantities > Graduated Symbols for some database field.

[image: Symbology Properties]

The Symbology icons are visible in Arcmap:

[image]

We published the map as a MapServer.

The Symbology icons are visible in the published Legend of the Arcgis MapServer as seen here:

[image: Legend]

But the Symbology icons are not visible in the rendered map image of the MapServer:

[image: Map Image]

Is there a special setting one needs to do in order to make the symbology icons visible in the exported map images of the MapServer?

Comment: The symbols in your second image are not the same as the symbols in your first image.  Your symbols appear to have been changed from graduated symbols to categories.

Comment: You are right Midavalo. It is my mistake. I took screenshots for different mxd files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a new layer using "Make a Query Layer" instead of "Make a Feature Layer". "Feature Layer" is used when the data comes from a FeatureClass. "Query Layer" is used when the data comes from a SQL query.